# Ruby Serializing Game Classes

Tags: ruby, serialization

I'm writing a simple command line game. I have a Game class that runs a loop and uses a Board class to display the player's moves. What I want to do is write the game class to a YAML file when the users wants to save the game's state, and load the YAML when the player resumes play. My issue is that I don't know how to recreate the object once I open the YAML file.

```
def save_game 
  yaml = YAML::dump(self)
  file = File.open("../data/Game.yml", 'w') {|file| file.write    yaml.to_yaml}
  exit 
end

def load_game 
  data = File.open("../data/Game.yml", "r") {|file| file.read}
  yaml = YAML::load(data)
end
```

The save game method works fine and I have my object serialized in the correct directory. The load_file displays the yaml object, but I don't know where to go from here.

This is the first project I have attempted serialization and deserialization, so if there are any additional resources you would reccommend for me to gain further knowledge in the subject please let me know.

Comment: This is awesome, so let me write a good example to help.

Comment: solved the issue, it has to do with how you're writing and reading YAML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote asciitrails.rb as a game to demonstrate saving and loading game state.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w
# asciitrails.rb
# Author: Andy Bettisworth
# Description: Walk the ASCII trails

module AsciiTrails
  require 'io/console'
  require 'yaml'

  attr_accessor :history

  class Game
    def start
      puts 'You are now walking the ASCII trails.'
      load_game
      game_loop
    end

    private

    def game_loop
      loop do
        move = get_move
        case move
        when "\e[A"
          @history << "MOVE UP"
          puts "[#{@history.count}] MOVE ARROW"
        when "\e[B"
          @history << "MOVE DOWN"
          puts "[#{@history.count}] MOVE DOWN"
        when "\e[C"
          @history << "MOVE RIGHT"
          puts "[#{@history.count}] MOVE RIGHT"
        when "\e[D"
          @history << "MOVE LEFT"
          puts "[#{@history.count}] MOVE LEFT"
        when "\u0003"
          @history << "PAUSE"
          puts "[#{@history.count}] PAUSE"
          save_game
          exit 0
        end
      end
    end

    def get_move
      STDIN.echo = false
      STDIN.raw!

      input = STDIN.getc.chr
      if input == "\e" then
        input << STDIN.read_nonblock(3) rescue nil
        input << STDIN.read_nonblock(2) rescue nil
      end
    ensure
      STDIN.echo = true
      STDIN.cooked!

      return input
    end

    def save_game
      File.open("./asciitrails.yml", 'w') { |f| YAML.dump([] << self, f) }
      exit
    end

    def load_game
      begin
        yaml = YAML.load_file("./asciitrails.yml")
        @history = yaml[0].history
      rescue
        @history = []
      end
    end
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $0
  include AsciiTrails

  game = Game.new
  game.start
end
```

Saving game state:

```
File.open("./asciitrails.yml", 'w') { |f| YAML.dump([] << self, f) }
```

Loading game state:

```
begin
   yaml = YAML.load_file("./asciitrails.yml")
   @history = yaml[0].history
rescue
   @history = []
end
```

When you're loading game state simply pull the variables you make use of.

Comment: Thank you @wurde, one issue was the way I was serializing my objects, once I serialized them the way you explained I had gotten another type of error which after looking into, I found the issue with my YAML was that I was serializing procs which caused the error. After reworking the procs I am now able to save my game state. Thank you again.

Comment: Glad to helped, it was fun. Could you vote this as your favorite answer?

Comment: This question is pretty old but accessing a variable this way @history = yaml[0].history always prints out errors for me. It prints something like undefined method `[]' for #<Hangman:0x00007fffbc550d98> (NoMethodError).